# What should I do if I want to group the data using column but want to put extra columns too in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, subquery

```
update s
set s.Date = f.Date
from SecondDates s 
inner join (select Location, max(Date) Date
            from FirstDates
            group by Location) f on f.Location = s.Location
```

What if more columns in `SecondTable` needs to be updated from `FirstTable`? E.g. `Set s.Name= f.Name, s.CellNo= f.CellNo`.

I know that we can select more columns in `select` statement i.e. `f` but grouping them would present unwanted results.

Answer (score 2):

If the are unique, you can also pick them through the sub query as below. This will only work if there only one Unique Name and CellNo available for a single location. Other case this will not work.

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Date = f.Date,
s.Name= f.Name, 
s.CellNo= f.CellNo
FROM SecondDates s 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Location,name,cellno, 
  MAX(Date) Date
  FROM FirstDates
  GROUP BY  name,cellno,Location
) f 
ON f.Location = s.Location
```

Comment: yeah but some are repeating

Comment: You can add some sample data from table FirstDates with repeating scenario. This will help to define the logic. You also define the logic for name you wants to use among repeating values.

Answer (score 1):

`APPLY` is probably the simplest solution:

```
update s
    set s.Date = fd.Date,
        s.Name = fd.Name,
        . . .
from SecondDates s cross apply
     (select top (1) fd.*
      from FirstDates
      where f.Location = s.Location
      order by f.date desc
     ) fd;
```

Another method would use `row_number()`:

```
update s
    set s.Date = fd.Date,
        s.Name = fd.Name,
        . . .
from SecondDates s join
     (select fd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location order by date desc) as seqnum
     ) fd
     on f.Location = s.Location
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GROUP BY Location` use `NOT EXISTS` to get the row with the last `Date` for each `Location` from `FirstDates`:

```
update s
set s.Date = f.Date, s.name = f.name, s.cellno = f.cellno
from SecondDates s inner join (
  select f.* from FirstDates f
  where not exists (
    select 1 from FirstDates
    where Location = f.Location and Date > f.Date
  )
) f on f.Location = s.Location
```